# Truncar casas decimais arbitrariamente com PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou fazendo um consulta SQL utilizando a função `sum()`. Essa função soma números inteiros e números fracionários. O problema é que ela retorna um *double precision* com número muito grande. Como faço para limitar até duas casas decimais depois do ponto?

Código

```
SELECT sum(comprimento * largura * qtde) as met FROM seccionada WHERE cod_secc = 'SE1'
```

Resultado da consulta:

> ```
> 40.1699985265732
> ```

Queria que a resposta fosse:

> ```
> 40.16
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isto existe esta função:

```
trunc( valor, [ casas_decimais ] )
```

e essa:

```
round( valor, [ casas_decimais ] )
```

A diferença das duas é que `trunc` não faz arredondamento, retornando `40.16` como pedido na sua pergunta, e o `round` retorna `40.17`.

Aplicada ao seu código:

```
SELECT
   trunc( sum(comprimento * largura * qtde), 2 ) as met
FROM
   seccionada
WHERE
   cod_secc = 'SE1'
```

Veja ambas em ação no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/12475)**.

Comment: Obrigado cara, o round é a melhor opção. Valeu..